# SQLITE3 - Update Query with left join

Tags: android, sqlite

In Android, is it possible to do execute update query with left join?

Example : `UPDATE fldMaster LEFT JOIN fieldsectionmap ON master_fldId = fieldsec_fieldid SET sortOrder = sortOrder - 1 WHERE  fieldsec_secid = 100207 AND sortOrder BETWEEN  39 AND 59`

Comment: If you want to update field sortOrder, why do you need a join? It's not in both tables is it?

Comment: no, fldmaster mapping is done in fieldsectionmap. So I want only particular mapped rows to be updated

Comment: Ah, I think I got you question now. Writing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your query to something like this:

```
UPDATE fldMaster SET sortOrder = sortOrder - 1 WHERE id IN 
(SELECT f.id FROM fldMaster f JOIN fieldsectionmap fsm ON ...)
```